# What is the difference between the mdoc macro set for troff and the plain man macro set for making new manpages

Tags: man, groff

I am trying to create man pages for a side project and I have never used troff before, and I am trying to figure out what exactly is the difference between the man macro set and the mdoc macro sets and which is more portable between POSIX OS'es and the various implementations of troff.

What I have noticed is that both mdoc and plain man share some macros and that BSD (at least FreeBSD) uses the mdoc manual format while GNU uses the plain man format.

So my questions are basically:

Is mdoc a superset of the man macros? and does that make using plain man legacy? The groff manpage for mdoc states that the plain man macros are the predecessor to mdoc but does not say if mdoc supersedes man.

Is the difference some BSD vs SYSV and/or GNU thing?

Which is more portable across POSIX systems and various implementations of troff other than groff (like heirloom troff)?

Comment: That's a broad topic which really calls for a side-by-side comparison.  However, none has been presented in earlier discussion.

Comment: From OpenBSD's `man 7 man`: "Do not use man to write your manuals: It lacks support for semantic markup.  Use the mdoc(7) language, instead."  Both `man(7)` and `mdoc(7)` are reasonably portable these days, but `mdoc(7)` is particularly nice if you have `mandoc(1)`.  Which, of course, is NIH for GNU.

Comment: So for all intent and practical purposes the mdoc is a modern replacement for the plain man?

Answer (score 9):

> What exactly is the difference between the `man` macro set and the `mdoc` macro sets?

`man` is minimal and simplistic, having only bare-bones commands to define section headings, paragraphs, and subheadings. The package includes some basic formatting commands like `.B`, `.BI`, and not much else.

`mdoc`, on the other hand, is a full-featured DSL of its own, with dedicated markup commands for common manpage elements like switches, option and parameter lists, function types and return values, flags, command synopses, and virtually everything you'd expect a manpage markup language to have. See [`mdoc(7)`](https://man.openbsd.org/mdoc.7) for a complete reference.

> Is `mdoc` a superset of the `man` macros?

No. `mdoc` and `man` are completely unrelated packages, sharing only a common ancestry and the same goal of marking up computer manual-pages.

> What I have noticed is that both `mdoc` and plain `man` share some macros

They don't share anything. It's possible that what you've seen are native Roff commands, which is the underlying typesetting language in which the `mdoc` and `man` macros are written in. These tend to be used heavily in documents which use `man`, but less so in those which use `mdoc`.

You can easily distinguish native Roff commands from macros by the way standard Roff packages capitalise their macro names. For `man`, each macro's name is uppercased, like `.PP`, `.TH`, `.SH`, etc. For `mdoc`, only the first letter is uppercased: `.Pp`, `.Dt`, `.Sh`, etc.

> The Groff manpage for `mdoc` states that the plain `man` macro's are the predecessor to `mdoc` but does not say if `mdoc` supersedes `man`.
>
> [`groff_mdoc(7)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=groff_mdoc&sektion=7)
> A complete reference for writing UNIX manual pages with the **-mdoc** macro package; a *content*-based and *domain*-based formatting package for GNU troff(1). Its predecessor, the **-man**(7) package, addressed page layout leaving the manipulation of fonts and other typesetting details to the individual author.

I don't think "predecessor" here was intended to mean anything more than "something similar which was being used before". :-)

> Which is more portable across POSIX systems and various implementations of `troff` other than Groff (like Heirloom Troff)?

The `mdoc` macros have been well-supported for a long time now, having first debuted in 4.4BSD and shipped with every Groff install by default. Both packages can be considered equally portable, unless you're preparing documents for antique terminals from the mid-70s. :)

> Is the difference some BSD vs SYSV and/or GNU thing?

You're on the right track. Modern BSD systems use a program called `mandoc` to format and display manpages, which is a clean reimplementation of `mdoc` using natively-compiled C. It only supports a subset of the Roff language — enough so that legacy manpages display correctly.

Mandoc isn't a true typesetting program the way Groff and Heirloom are. Its focus is specifically on computer manuals: and only documents authored with `mdoc` are guaranteed to render consistently and correctly on BSD-derived platforms. More detailed criticisms of `man` can be found in [`man(7)`](https://man.openbsd.org/man.7).

> and does that make using plain `man` legacy?

Kind of. Unless you're an experienced manpage author with a sound understanding of Roff grammar and the pipeline's mechanics, you really shouldn't be using anything other than `mdoc` for authoring your manual-pages. Veteran `troff` users may find `mdoc` to be needlessly verbose or restrictive, finding `man` to be lighter and less intrusive. However, these authors are experienced enough to know damn well what they're doing ― **so unless you're a grizzled veteran, just stick to using `mdoc`**.

#### Further info

If you're interested in learning more about Roff history, and this answer wasn't [FMTEYEWTK](https://www.definition-of.com/FMTEYEWTK) already, here're some links to authoritative learning material:

- [History of UNIX Manpages](https://manpages.bsd.lv/history.html): Comprehensive timeline of over 50 years of evolution
- [CSTR #54](https://www.troff.org/54.pdf): PDF version of the original Nroff/Troff User's Manual – widely considered to be the Troff Bible
- [*"Deprecating Groff for BSD manual display"*](https://2009.asiabsdcon.org/papers/abc2009-P6B-paper.pdf): A paper by the author of `mandoc`, which explains the reasoning for `man`'s obsolescence.

Comment: Being new to Troff, one thing that I don't understand is whether "macros" are real macros or not. Because, if both Troff and `mandoc` are nothing but `roff` macros, I guess that you could just substitute the macros into their `roff` code -with a preprocessor-, and then `mandoc` would be displayed fine in very old ancient Unices, wouldn't it?

Comment: @cesss your terminology might be a bit mixed up; `mandoc` is a program, `mdoc` is a format.  `man` and `mdoc` define a set of macros, and `troff` treats them as "real" macros and produces a `roff` intermediate format via textual expansion.  `mandoc` on the other hand does not treat them as "real" macros: it parses them to an AST, which it can then render for terminals without an intermediate `roff` format.

Comment: @p00ya Thanks a lot for your clarification. Does this mean that you can take a file in `mdoc` format, pass it to `troff` and it will work correctly? Or does the `mdoc` format define new things that are supported by `mandoc` but not by `troff` ?

Comment: Yes, files written with `mdoc` will work correctly with both modern `troff` and `mandoc`.  However, as the answer points out, `mdoc` may not work with `troff` from very old (1970s) UNIX systems.  In that case, you could theoretically use a modern system to generate the "physical" `roff` commands from an `mdoc` input, and then copy that to the old system.